# Why can't I get HAL support to work in grails 2.3.8?

Tags: rest, grails, hateoas

I am following the directions in the docs, here:

http://grails.org/doc/2.3.8/guide/webServices.html#hypermedia

Why won't grails produce HAL-formatted output, as shown in the documentation?

I have a domain object which I have mapped with the @Resource annotation:

```
@Resource(uri='/documentCatalogs', formats = ['json', 'xml'], readOnly = true)
class DocumentCatalog {
    String entityType
    String actionCode
    ...
}
```

...and in my conf/spring/resources.groovy, I have configured the HAL JSON renderer beans:

```
import com.cscinfo.platform.api.formslibrary.DocumentCatalog
import grails.rest.render.hal.HalJsonCollectionRenderer
import grails.rest.render.hal.HalJsonRenderer

// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
    halDocumentCatalogRenderer(HalJsonRenderer, DocumentCatalog)
    halDocumentCatalogCollectionRenderer(HalJsonCollectionRenderer, DocumentCatalog)
}
```

Using the debugger, I confirmed that the initialize() method on HalJsonRenderer is called and that it is constructed with the correct targetType.

I send a rest call using Postman:

```
http://localhost:8080/formslibrary/documentCatalogs/3
Accept application/hal+json
```

And I get back a response which is regular JSON and doesn't contain any links:

```
{
    "class": "com.cscinfo.platform.api.formslibrary.DocumentCatalog",
    "id": 3,
    "actionCode": "WITH",
    "entityType": "LLP",
...
}
```

What did I miss? Is there some plugin or configuration setting I have to enable for this behavior? Is there some additional mapping property somewhere that's not documented?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out! There are multiple aspects of the fix...

I had to add "hal" as one of the listed formats in the @Resource annotation:

```
@Resource(uri='/documentCatalogs', formats = ['json', 'xml', 'hal'])
```

Some hunting around in the debugger revealed that Grails will blithely ignore the `Accept` header, based on the UserAgent string that is sent from the client. (In my case, since I'm using Postman,  it was the Google Chrome UA string.)

One workaround for the `Accept` header issue is to add ".hal" to the end of the URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/formslibrary/documentCatalogs/3.hal
```

This isn't a very good solution IMO, since the HAL URLs generated by the renderer don't end in ".hal" by default.

A better solution is to fix Grails' handling of the accept header by updating the config. In Config.groovy, you will see a line that says:

```
grails.mime.disable.accept.header.userAgents = ['Gecko', 'WebKit', 'Presto', 'Trident']
```

Change it to:

```
grails.mime.disable.accept.header.userAgents = ['None']
```

This forces Grails to honor the `Accept` header, regardless of the user agent.

Hope this helps somebody else who's hitting the same issue.

P.S. It's really helpful to put a breakpoint in the `ResponseMimeTypesApi#getMimeTypesFormatAware(...)` method.

Comment: For some reason i do not get the _embedded entities when using thi approach. May you have an ideay why?

Comment: In the end, we found that the default HAL output was so inconsistent with what we expected that we ended up writing our own HAL plugin for use within the company. I will see if I can get permission to publish it publicly as an official Grails plugin.